# Mysqli not inserting data

Tags: php, post, mysqli

Hello I am trying the following code block and not getting an error though also not getting the data inserted into the database.  Also, the POST values are being sent.

Any help is appreciated:

```
    if(!empty($firstName) && !empty($lastName) && !empty($cell)){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM clientInformation WHERE firstName = '$firstName' AND lastName = '$lastName' AND cell = '$cell' LIMIT 1;";

    if(!$result = $con->query($sql)){
        die('There was an error running the query [' . $con->error . ']');  
        }else{

            $numRows = $result->num_rows;


        }

        if($numRows > 0){

            $newResult = $result->fetch_assoc();

        }else{

    $sql = "INSERT INTO clientInformation (firstName, lastName, address, city, zip, phone, cell, state, email) VALUES ('$firstName', '$lastName', '$address', '$city', '$zip', '$phone', '$cell', '$state', '$email');";


            if(!$result = $con->query($sql)){
        die('There was an error running the query [' . $con->error . ']');  
        }

        }       
}
```

Comment: I can see you're already echoing out stuff to find the issue. What is being echoed/printed? ie what IF is returning TRUE and whatnot. is `$numRows > 0` true?

Comment: I think it's the second query won't run for some reason.  I made changes to it as the SQL was a little off but now the sql runs fine in PHPMYADMIN but still I cannot get the second query to run. This is my first time using mysqli so I'm thinking I'm having some issues figuring it out.

Comment: **You are leaving yourself wide open to SQL injection attacks.**  Also, any input data with single quotes in it, like a name of "O'Malley", will blow up your SQL query. Please learn about using parametrized queries, preferably with the PDO module, to protect your web app.  http://bobby-tables.com/php has examples to get you started.

Comment: The strings are being escaped so the "O'Malley" name shouldn't be an issue.  I'll have to look over parametized queries though as I'm not familiar with them. As far as the code working though do you see anything that would make the INSERT not work?

Answer (score 0):

You have a semicolon inside values right after $firstName

```
... VALUES ($firstName; $lastName, ....
```

replace this semicolon with comma, see if it works.

Comment: I think it's the second query won't run for some reason.  I made changes to it as the SQL was a little off but now the sql runs fine in PHPMYADMIN but still I cannot get the second query to run. This is my first time using mysqli so I'm thinking I'm having some issues figuring it out.